# How do I remove the nth digit of a consecutive set of numbers using a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am a beginner in Java coding and I was wondering how I could use a for loop to decrease the numbers in a string for something like: 1000 100 10 1

```
for(int a = 1000; a <= 1; a--) {
    System.out.print(a);            
}
```

**Expected output: ** 1000 100 10 1

Comment: Use substring. It's easier

Comment: Remember Java and Javascript are two very different languages, can you please specify which that is and remove the tag of the one that isn't? Thanks

Comment: What is your question? It will also be helpful if you post whatever you have already tried.

Comment: It's Java. I'm trying to use a for loop to remove the last digit of a string consecutively say like 10000 1000 100 10 1.

Comment: @EpisodeShi - Post whatever you have tried. Also, post a sample input and the expected output for it.

Comment: What `string` are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the output just instead of decrementing the value divide it by 10:

```
for (int a = 1000; a >= 1; a = a / 10) {
    System.out.print(a + " ");
}
```

**Output:** 1000 100 10 1

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using `.substring` like so:

```
s.substring(0, s.length()-1)
```

If you want to keep on looping until the String is 0 characters long, just do:

```
    String str = "10000";
    while(str.length()>1){
        str=str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```